# Arduino websockets send id in connection

Tags: esp8266

I am creating home automation using esp's and little home server. Idea is to connect arduinos to server, add each of them id and let them talk via websockets with server and server will forward (by some logic inside) messages to different arduinos. Pretty simple.

What I found, is that I cannot tell, what websocket client I am talking to. I use simple example from lib: https://github.com/gilmaimon/ArduinoWebsockets

```
client.onMessage(onMessageCallback);
client.onEvent(onEventsCallback);
client.connect(websockets_server_host, websockets_server_port, "/");
client.ping();
```

My idea is to send id of arduino with connection handshake. Is it even possible?

Comment: This is a websocket *client* code. The client is not talking to other clients, but the server. He doesn't need to differentiate clients.

Comment: Exactly. Server will forward messages from one client to antoher. Problem is, that on server side I have multiple clients, that I cannot distinguish so I need each client to identify itself when it connect

Comment: You can even add your device id with every message you send to the server.

Comment: I like to pass a an identifying GET param in the websocket URL (eg. `system_get_chip_id()`), then the PC-based server socket lib has a (sometimes roundabout) way of getting the request URL to id who's asking.